# Adding 4 Drinks to a Station in Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, models, formtastic

I have two models: Stations & Drinks

Stations has_many :drinks and Drinks belongs_to :stations

I'm trying to make my form so that when you create a station, you can select 4 drinks that will belong to that station as well.

Original form:

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @station] do |f| %>
<fieldset class="inputs">
    <ol>
        <%=f.input :name %>
        <%=f.input :number, :as => :number %>
    </ol>
</fieldset>
<%= f.buttons :commit %>
```

I've been trying to figure out how to create 4 (select) input fields in this form so that you can select Drink #1, #2, #3, #4 for the current station. Any ideas?

I'm currently trying `accepts_nested_attributes_for :drinks, :allow_destroy => true.`

**Drinks** belongs_to :station

```
id | name | station_id |
```

**Stations** has_many :drinks

```
id | name |
```

.

**UPDATE**
As noted below by tihm, you can add 4 drinks and edit their values with this:

```
<% f.fields_for :drinks do |drink_form| %>
            <%# Put your inputs here...could be a select box %>
            <%= drink_form.select :name, [['Drink #1', 'drink_1'],['Drink #2', drink_2] %>  

            <%# Or a plain input %>
            <%= drink_form.input :description %>  

            <%# ... Any other drink attributes ... %>
        <% end %>
```

However, what I'm trying to do is generate four select boxes that each list `Drink.all` and be able to swap out one drink object with a different one. So, when you change the value of the first select box from coke to pepsi, it removes the station_id from coke, and adds the station_id to pepsi.

I don't need to be able to edit the drink attributes.. I just need to change which drinks are associated with this station. Is this possible in the same form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a "best-practice" rails way of doing... so I ended up doing a bunch of AJAX / custom ruby code to implement it. Here it is (maybe it'll help someone else):

```
<% @drinks = Drink.all %>
    <fieldset class="inputs">
        <ol>
        <% @station.drinks.each_with_index do |d,i| %>
            <li>
                <label class="label" for="station_name">Item</label>
                <%=select("drink", "id", @drinks.collect { |d| [d.name,d.id] }, {:include_blank => true, :selected => d.id}, {:class => "station-items"})%>
            </li>
        <% end %>
        <% m = 4-@station.drinks.count %>
        <% m.times do %>
            <li>
                <label class=" label" for="station_name">Item</label>
                <%=select("drink", "id", @drinks.collect { |d| [d.name,d.id] }, {:include_blank => true}, {:class => "station-items"})%>
            </li>
        <% end %>
        </ol>
    </fieldset>
    <%= f.buttons :commit %>
<% end %>

<script>    
$(".station-items").on("change",function(){
  var node = $(this)
  , prev = node.attr('data-rel')
  , next = parseInt(node.val())
  , station_id = $("#station_id").val()

  if(next) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/drinks/"+next+".json",
      type: "PUT",
      data: { id:next, "drink[station_id]":station_id }
    });
  }

  if(prev) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/drinks/"+prev+".json",
      type: "PUT",
      data: { id:prev, "drink[station_id]":"" }
    });
  }

  $(this).attr('data-rel',next);
});

$('.station-items option:selected').each(function(){
  return $(this).parent().attr('data-rel',$(this).val())
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to start by watching:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

If you know you'll always have 4 or less, then it's a bit easier and you can skip the js from the Railscasts.

In your controller, be sure to build the empty drink objects you need:

```
....
@station = Station.new
4.times do
  @station.drinks.build
end
...
```

This way, the #fields_for in the view has objects to iterate over. In your view, something ilke:

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @station] do |f| %>
<fieldset class="inputs">
    <ol>
        <%=f.input :name %>
        <%=f.input :number, :as => :number %>
        <% f.fields_for :drinks do |drink_form| %>
            <%# Put your inputs here...could be a select box %>
            <%= drink_form.select :name, [['Drink #1', 'drink_1'],['Drink #2', drink_2] %>  

            <%# Or a plain input %>
            <%= drink_form.input :description %>  

            <%# ... Any other drink attributes ... %>
        <% end %>
    </ol>
</fieldset>
<%= f.buttons :commit %>
```

The #select will depend a lot on what you are selecting from and the structure of that data. Is it coming from a model, a simple list, etc.

Comment: That worked well for a regular Rails app. Also, if anyone is looking for a solution to use with Active Admin (which I also needed): https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/59 has resolved the issue.

Comment: Okay, initially I thought this was what I needed. However, it's a bit trickier than that. What you have specified above allows me to edit the content (name,description,etc) of 4 drinks associated with a station. However, I need to be able to swap the ACTUAL drink at point #1. So, for example, instead of editing the name of drink #1 from pepsi to coke, I need to change the drink from pepsi object to coke object.